# How to get all parks of the world with address and lat/lng

Tags: dictionary, geolocation, geospatial, geography, gis

I am trying to import a list of all parks in the world and data about them.  I need the following information:

- Park name
- Address
- Owner (state, country or county or city)
- Latitude/Longtitude (but presumably I can get that from the address)

Is there any place to import such a thing?

Comment: What sorts of parks? Amusement parks? Only 'big' parks (like National Parks except worldwide) or do small city parks count? I really, highly doubt such a list exists anywhere available if you need it to be truly worldwide. Also, I'm not really sure this is the best place to ask this question.

Comment: Not amusement parks or playgrounds :) More like places to hike or be in nature.  But city parks are needed too since there are many great city parks which are good for hiking and being outdoors. To clarify, the site I am making it for is http://www.comehike.com so it might explain the kinds of parks I need.  Thanks!

Comment: Huh. Well, that's a pretty ambitious project -- to document all locations worldwide that are good for hiking (and laid aside especially for it since really anywhere could be good for hiking ;) ). I've been doing some looking and can't find much other than you having to manually compile a list. Not what you want to hear, I know. Sorry...

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid doing it manually since there probably are betweek 10k-20k parks in the world :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get it from openstreetmap.org - crowdsourced map data. Perhaps things tagged leisure=park:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:leisure%3Dpark

or boundary=national_park:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dnational_park

Not sure about getting the 'owner' or 'address' - many of these things will be national properties, with no address as such. "National Parks" here in the UK, for example, are different to National Parks in the USA. Here it's just a designation of certain special applicable laws in the region relating to conservation and tourism, and land ownership is unaffected, whereas in the USA, I believe, the land is all owned by the nation.